# Does the SecretManagerServiceClient persist secrets across stop/start instances?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to use a secrets manager rather than environment variables for db passwords and so on.  But, I'm worried about performance during container initialization if an API call is required each time to fetch the secrets.

[GCP Cloud Tips](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips) says:

> Because container instances are scaled as needed, a typical method is to initialize the execution environment completely. This kind of initialization is called "cold start". If a client request triggers a cold start, the container instance startup results in additional latency.
>
> ...
>
> Optimizing for service startup speed minimizes the latency that delays a container instance from serving requests.

and

> In Cloud Run, you cannot assume that service state is preserved between requests. However, Cloud Run does reuse individual container instances to serve ongoing traffic, so you can declare a variable in global scope to allow its value to be reused in subsequent invocations. Whether any individual request receives the benefit of this reuse cannot be known ahead of time.

It's hard to tell from the following [sample code](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#secretmanager-create-secret-csharp) for the secrets manager if anything is being stored in a global variable for performance.  I tried and couldn't find the source code for SecretManagerServiceClient on GitHub.

```
public static void AccessSecretVersion(string projectId, string secretId, string secretVersion)
{
    SecretManagerServiceClient client = SecretManagerServiceClient.Create();

    // Create the request.
    var request = new AccessSecretVersionRequest
    {
        SecretVersionName = new SecretVersionName(projectId, secretId, secretVersion),
    };

    // Access the secret and print the result.
    //
    // WARNING: Do not print secrets in production environments. This
    // snippet is for demonstration purposes only.
    var version = client.AccessSecretVersion(request);
    string payload = version.Payload.Data.ToStringUtf8();
    Console.WriteLine($"Payload: {payload}");
}
```

Anyone know if the secrets would persist across Cloud Run instances as they are stopped and restarted?

Answer (score 0):

Secret Manager client libraries use the Secret Manager API which is separate from Cloud Run. The secret data is not stored inside your Cloud Run container instances.

That said, Cloud Run instances are not "stopped and restarted", it's rather "they're destroyed and re-created" based on scaling needs. So the state each container instance holds will be destroyed, your container needs to access the secret every time it starts.

Comment: From my post: "Cloud Run does reuse individual container instances".  How else would cloud run be doing that without "docker stop" and "docker start", ultimately?  When the docs say global vars persist, that's the scenario I'm referring to, not the scenario where the containers are killed and global vars destroyed.

Comment: You said: "Secret Manager client libraries use the Secret Manager API which is separate from Cloud Run."  Agreed.  I'm trying to understand whether SecretManagerServiceClient's implementation has stopping/starting of containers in mind using global variables.  I only mention cloud run as a reference.  I don't have enough SO karma to create a google-cloud-secret-manager tag, or I would have.

Comment: To your first comment: Cloud Run doesn’t even use docker. So no, there’s no docker stop/start. If a container is no longer used. It’s deleted. New containers are freshly created. However a container instance may handle many requests while it’s still active.

Comment: To answer your second comment: No, Secret Manager client library does not factor that in. As developer, it’s your responsibility to retrieve the secret and store it in a variable ($payload above) upon need (or upon startup of process). The client library wouldn’t care about how/where you’re running your application.

Comment: "Cloud Run doesn’t even use docker".  It doesn't?  What does it use?  I just created a Dockerfile and deployed it to cloud run yesterday per the official GCP Cloud Run docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy).

Comment: Yes, but docker images (a.k.a. OCI images) are standard and can be executed by other container runtimes. As a user you don't need to care how your container is executed. I recommend re-reading docs or https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq to understand the lifecycle model.

Comment: "The secret data is not stored inside your Cloud Run container instances." is so far the only response to my original question and lacks any references (source code, docs, or excerpts) to back it up.  I'd like to see if others can weigh in with more detail.